# Asymptotic upper and lower bound of $\frac{1}{n^c}$?

Tags: asymptotics

Given a cost function like this $f(n)=\frac{1}{n^c}$ where $c \ge 1$, can we say that $f(n)=o(n)$ and $f(n)=O(n^2)$ are all correct upper bounds, but $f(n)=\Omega(n!)$ and $f(n)=\Omega(2^{n/1000})$ are not correct?

The problem with $f(n)=\frac{1}{n^c}$ is that it decreases as $n$ increases... so for large value of $n$, the function goes to zero.

Answer (score 2):

We can check [the definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).

You have that $\frac{f(n)}{n}=\frac{1}{n^{c+1}}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore $f\in o(n)$. You also have that for $n>1$ $|f(n)|\leq 1\leq n^2$. Therefore, $f\in O(n^2)$.

However, for all $C>0$ we have some $n$ such that $Cn!\leq \frac{1}{n^c}=f(n)$ is not satisfied. It is enough to take $n$ such that $Cn!>1$. Therefore, $f\not\in \Omega(n!)$. Similarly for all $C>0$ we can find $n$ such that $C2^{n/1000}\leq \frac{1}{n^c}=f(n)$ is not satisfied. Note that these two negative claims happen for any $c$.

Comment: Thanks @sapphire ! Your explanation for $o(n)$ and $O(n^2)$ looks good.

Answer (score -1):

Let me elaborate more on $\Omega(n!)$ and $\Omega(2^{n/1000})$:

$f(n)=\Omega(n!) \implies f(n) \geq c \cdot n! \implies \frac{1}{n^c} \geq c \cdot n!$

Given some constant $c \geq 1$ and $n \geq n_0$ where $n_0 = 1$, we can clearly see that $\frac{1}{n^c} \leq c \cdot n!$ for all $c \geq 1$ and $n \geq 1$.

Hence, $\Omega(n!)$ cannot be a lower bound for $f(n)$.

We can use the same logic for $\Omega(2^{n/1000})$. Specifically:

Since $\Omega(2^{n/1000}) = \Omega(2^n)$ for large values of $n$: $\frac{1}{n^c}$ is always less than or equal to $2^n$ (provided that $c\geq 1$).

Hence, $\Omega(2^{n/1000})$ cannot be a lower bound for $f(n)$.

Is that explanation sound?

Comment: You might want to denote the two constants by different names, to avoid confusion. Like $c_1$ and $c_2$

Comment: Also, it isnt correct to say that $2^{\frac{n}{1000}}=\Omega(2^n)$, but it is polynomially equivalent to it. (On the other hand, its true that $2^{\frac{n}{1000}}=O(2^n)$)

Comment: Thanks @nirshahar .. maybe I can say that: $\Omega(2^{n/1000}) = \Omega(2^n)$ for large $n \geq 1000$ ?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. $2^n = (2^{\frac{n}{1000}})^{1000}$. So, what you are saying is somewhat equivalent to saying that for $n>1000$ we have $\Omega(n)=\Omega(n^{1000})$. This clearly does not make any sense.

Comment: So what are the suggests to make the answer logical? should I replace 

"Since $\Omega(2^{n/1000}) = \Omega(2^n) $ for large values of  n"

with

"Since $\Omega(2^{n/1000})$ is polynomially equivalent to $\Omega(2^n) $ for large values of  n"

?

Comment: No, its just that $\frac{1}{n^c}$ is a function that decreases to $0$ while $2^{\frac{n}{1000}}$ is a function that grows to infinity, so its impossible that $\frac{1}{n^c}$ to be $\Omega(2^{\frac{n}{1000}})$